# tableutils filter input move outside table

Tags: javascript, jquery

this [NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/8etdnpdt/4/) show a text inside table,where i can filter data, however i don't want the input to be inside the table,i want to map to another input or removed it from the table and placed it outside.

Not working on my file :

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tableutils.js"></script>


    <script>
        function searchRecords() {

            $('#searchMe').tableutils({
                filter: {
                    type: ['text']
                },
                fixHeader: {
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 200
                },

                columns: [{
                    label: 'First Name'
                }, {
                    label: 'Last Name'
                }, {
                    label: 'Concept'
                }, {
                    label: 'Rating'
                }, {
                    label: 'AKA'
                }]
            });

            $('#searchRecords').hide();
        }

        searchRecords();

$('#filter_searchMe_0').css('width','100px').detach().appendTo( "#outSide" );
</script>

<body onload="searchRecords();">
<div id="outSide"></div>
<div class="demoContentDIV">
    <ul id="allDemos" style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li id="searchContent">
            <table id="searchMe" width="980px">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="20%">First Name</th>
                        <th width="20%">Last Name</th>
                        <th width="10%">Concept</th>
                        <th width="10%">Rating</th>
                        <th width="40%">AKA</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">Tony</td>
                        <td width="20%">Stark</td>
                        <td width="10%">Marvel</td>
                        <td width="10%">42</td>
                        <td width="40%">Iron Man</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">Jack</td>
                        <td width="20%">Sparrow</td>
                        <td width="10%">Disney</td>
                        <td width="10%">40</td>
                        <td width="40%">Pirate</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">Bruce</td>
                        <td width="20%">Banner</td>
                        <td width="10%">Marvel</td>
                        <td width="10%">38</td>
                        <td width="40%">The Hulk</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">Clarke</td>
                        <td width="20%">Kent</td>
                        <td width="10%">DC</td>
                        <td width="10%">35</td>
                        <td width="40%">Man of Steel</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">Bruce</td>
                        <td width="20%">Wayne</td>
                        <td width="10%">DC</td>
                        <td width="10%">34</td>
                        <td width="40%">The Dark Knight</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">Sherlock</td>
                        <td width="20%">Holmes</td>
                        <td width="10%">Doyle</td>
                        <td width="10%">37</td>
                        <td width="40%">Ingenious</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">Captain</td>
                        <td width="20%">America</td>
                        <td width="10%">Marvel</td>
                        <td width="10%">39</td>
                        <td width="40%">Captain America</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">Peter</td>
                        <td width="20%">Parkar</td>
                        <td width="10%">Marvel</td>
                        <td width="10%">43</td>
                        <td width="40%">Spidy</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to deal it with that plugin. But you can simply do it with `jQuery`. just detach that element and append where ever you want.

This plugin uses id for the each filter input in this format.

`#filter_tableSelector_columnIndex`

so you can easily code like this to do that.

`$('#filter_searchMe_0').css('width','100px').detach().appendTo( "#outSide" );`

In this code I have removed the first column's filter input `(column Index = 0)` and append it to out side of the table.

I did **<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/8etdnpdt/7/)</kbd>** from your **<kbd>[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/8etdnpdt/4/)</kbd>**

**UPDATE:**

If you want to filter using first column use this `$('#filter_searchMe_0')`.

If you want to filter using second column use this `$('#filter_searchMe_1')`.

If you want to filter using third column use this `$('#filter_searchMe_2')`.

like that, you can use filter for your next columns too.

use this code to filter using 3rd column.
`$('#filter_searchMe_2').css('width','100px').detach().appendTo( "#outSide" );`

Comment: Try this solution @bumbumpaw

Comment: hi sir, do you only change my html and js area? @CJ Ramki

Comment: its working on fiddle,but  cant work it out on my file

Comment: sir i want to filter using the 3rd column, im using this `$('#filter_searchMe_0').css('width','100px').detach().appendTo( "#outSide" );` but it does not work

Comment: I edited my answer. See `UPDATE` section in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58938/discussion-between-bumbumpaw-and-cj-ramki).